# Relation between integers and greatest integer functions.

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I'm a bit lost on this example that was worked in class as our professor essentially used the famous "it's easy to show" explanation of the given property,

If $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $x \leq y$, then $[x]\leq[y]$ where $[x],[y]$ are the greatest integer functions.

I understand this property and it seems very straightforward though I'm not sure how one would go and prove this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$
[z]=max\{m \in \mathbb{Z} ; m \leq z\}.
$$
So if $x \leq y$ we have
$$
\{m \in \mathbb{Z} ; m \leq x\} \subset \{m \in \mathbb{Z} ; m \leq y\}
$$
Then
$$
[x]=max\{m \in \mathbb{Z} ; m \leq x\}\leq max \{m \in \mathbb{Z} ; m \leq y\}=[y].
$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I knew it was something relatively easy.

Comment: You are welcome! ; )